# .htaccess: Rewrite path internally without redirecting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, webserver

I can access my web server as follows: `https://www.example.com/my_old_folder/some_folder/`

There's an `.htaccess` file in `/my_old_folder/` with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^my_old_folder/(.*) my_new_folder/$1
```

I want to rewrite the folder `my_old_folder` internally to `my_new_folder`, without changing the URL in the browser. Just grab the files from `/my_new_folder/` instead of `/my_old_folder/`. If there's another folder like `/some_folder/` in this case, keep it. Only change the name `/my_old_folder/` to `/my_new_folder/`.

Unfortunately, it's not rewriting the path, although I already tried many solutions from the internet, including the above one.

Who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/my_old_folder/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* /my_new_folder/$0 [L]
```

It is because all path matching is relative to `my_old_folder/` inside `/my_old_folder/.htaccess`.

Comment: This gives me an `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: I'd say this implements a rewriting loop... You'd have to use an absolute path as target, so `/my_new_folder/...`

Comment: @anubhava This seems to work, but this also redirects/changes the URL in the browser.

Comment: No URL change in browser if you keep a trailing slash in original URL i.e. `https://www.example.com/my_old_folder/`